# Is there a way to repeat a function on a whole dataset n times in R?

Tags: r, loops, apply, replicate, rep

Feels like this is a super basic question but I'm a bit stuck.

Let's say I have a dataset of 100 items:

```
    x <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
```

I want to generate a new object which consists of x shuffled 10,000 times using `sample(x, size=100, replace=F)`. As in, what I want to end up with isn't these repeats all shuffled together but so that each item in x has to appear once before any can appear twice, etc.

I feel like this ought to be super simple but can't think what to do? My first thought was `rep()` but that gives me the same shuffling n times, and I want each shuffle to be independent. I tried

```
        repeat{ 
        sample(x, size=100, replace=F)
        i <- i + 1
        if (i == n){
        break
        }
        }
```

but that's incredibly slow even for a small number of repeats. Also thought about `apply` family but seems like they're intended to repeat a command for every item in a list, not do something to the entire list a number of times? (please correct me if that's wrong!)

I'd v much appreciate any help!

Comment: check out the `replicate` function

Comment: `permutations` doesn't have a `shuffle` function.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `permute` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/permute/versions/0.9-5/topics/shuffle

Comment: No need to use `shuffle`, just use `sample()`. Is `as.vector(replicate(10000,sample(x))` what you want?

Comment: You may [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66123263/edit) your questions.

Comment: Thanks everyone, really helpful advice! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer derived from comments to question:

```
    reps <- as.vector(replicate(sample(x, replace = F, size = length(x)), n = 10000, simplify = F)
```

And then to convert it to a more usable format,

```
    reps <- as.numeric(unlist(reps))
```